# Why do Ruby and Python have the % for formatting instead of "format"

Tags: python, ruby, format

I mean what makes `%` look so much attractive compared to good old `.format`?!

I know this may be subjective, but I wonder if there is something about this.

Comment: The use of `%` for formatting in Python 3 has been deprecated in favour of a [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, which was introduced in Python 2.6.

Comment: @Greg "deprecated" in the most lightest of light ways.

Comment: Its shorter and therefore better.

Comment: @Devin Jeanpierre: That's right, I'm just pointing out that "instead of format" is no longer true for Python.

Answer (score 5):

They inherit them from C. Specifically, [sprintf](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Formatted-Output-Functions.html).

Comment: But exactly in C is not "%" is sprintf

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume they use `%` because that's what the old C `printf` format strings looked like.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a piece of syntactic sugar, meant to make a common operation more terse. If you don't like it, you can use str.format() instead. I enjoy it because it makes printf()-style formatting stand out in the code.